# Elasticsearch on amazon ec2 t2micro instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2

I have launched one ec2 t2micro instance at amazon aws, which is the free tier and it offers only 1gb of ram.

I followed this [link](https://www.elastic.co/blog/running-elasticsearch-on-aws) in order to install `elasticsearch` on the amazon ec2 linux instance I created, but when I do this `sudo service elasticsearch start` it returns the following:

```
There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 986513408 bytes for committing reserved memory.
An error report file with more information is saved as:
/tmp/jvm-5303/hs_error.log
```

Inside the `log` file I found this:

```
Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again`.
```

So I did this `ulimit -c unlimited` but the same message appears again.

After that I updated the `/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/jvm.options` file with these values `-Xms512m -Xmx512m`, but the same message appears.

Any ideas what I might be missing and how I can `sudo service elasticsearch start` successfully?

Comment: You can also try `ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx512m" ` in  `elasticsearch.conf` or while starting elasticsearch manually pass parameters directly: `/opt/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -Xmx512m -Xms512`. But I think 1GB of RAM is not enough for fully functional ELK stack, I also once tried to run ELK on t2micro but even changing memory parameters didn't work and I had to move to better instance.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Micheal Dz ,  I have two `elasticsearch.conf` files `/usr/lib/sysctl.d/elasticsearch.conf` `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/elasticsearch.conf` and both are empty, so which one should I add the values?

Comment: I meant `elasticsearch.conf` in `/etc/elasticsearch`.

Comment: While 1GB (512MB heap) is probably more of a demo environment, it should work and I've done so quite a few times; also the elastic.co cloud offering is starting with 1GB instances. I'd set the heap size in the jvm.options as [described in the docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/heap-size.html). If it still fails after setting it there, please post the complete log.